# ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid, while installing nvidia on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, kernel

NVIDIA has stopped working after update and my Ubuntu is unable to find the second monitor. I've tried many different ways installing NVIDIA (software and updates, local run-file [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run) [Root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147651/nvidia-drivers-dont-work-with-mainline-kernel), apt-get install, and adding a ppa) but no luck. All of the above methods generate the same error (sample error in crash file).

```
DKMSBuildLog:
'DKMS make.log for nvidia-430.40 for kernel 4.18.0-25-generic (x86_64)'
 Sun Aug  4 19:41:32 KST 2019
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
 test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (       \
 echo >&2;                          \
 echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";      \
 echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
 echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."; \
```

Both files `auto.conf` and `autoconf.h`are even there. I couldn't find any other useful information in the crash file and I've tried many existing solution other than above-mentioned. Some of them have tried reinstalling the Ubuntu, I know it can resolve the issue but I can't afford to reinstall. Looking forward for a possible solution, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the files are in this precise directory, not for some different kernel version?

Comment: @DanielB. Yes. ` /usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic/include/config/auto.conf` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic/include/generated/autoconf.h'

Comment: DKMS on first few lines: Earlier versions of the run file (with Ubuntu LTS 14.04) presented a choice whether to install dkms. If I remember correctly enabling dkms also required the inclusion of some "32bit" stuff too, to allow it to install properly - even with this I never got dkms to work at that time though. So ended up disabling both. Always installing from recovery mode.

Comment: Have you ever found a sollution to this issue? I have encountered exactly the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.